# How to get value of dom element whose id having dot and dollar sign

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am facing problem with getting value of an element whose `id` contains special character as `.` and `$` sign.

my id to element is `"XS_19MAY2016_012720_311.04$_cal"` I am using syntax of jQuery as:

```
$("#"+xyz+"_cal").val()   where xyz is variable having above id.
```

I am getting  error as:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #XS_19MAY2016_012720_311.04$_cal.
```

What I doing wrong or what I need to do to correct it.

Comment: because of dot inside your id.  we can get any element object via this  $('.class'); or $('#id').

Comment: use vanilla way `document.getElementById('')`

Comment: I have checked it on my side by replacing id with  var xyz = "XS_19MAY2016_012720_31104";
  alert( $("#"+xyz+"_cal").val()  );  <input id="XS_19MAY2016_012720_31104_cal" value="5"/> . it is working.

Comment: if its input this will work `$("input[id='XS_19MAY2016_012720_311.04$_cal']")` or replace with div depending on your element

Answer (score 6):

Just escape the characters:

```js
var foo = 'XS_19MAY2016_012720_311.04$';
$('#' + foo.replace(/[.$]/g, '\\$&') + '_cal').text('foo')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="XS_19MAY2016_012720_311.04$_cal"></div>
```

Comment: Ya but OP is using a variable, concatenates with a string, as selector

Answer (score 5):

You can use this way to do that (**without symbol escaping**).

```js
$(function() {
  
  var 
    id = "XS_19MAY2016_012720_311.04$_cal",
    text;

  text = $('[id="' + id +'"]').text();
  
  alert(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="XS_19MAY2016_012720_311.04$_cal">Yay!</div>
```

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that you can drop the tag name from the selector and it will still work.  (Performance blah blah blah)

Comment: @Archer, Yes, you are completely right. I have forgot to drop It. Thanks! I have just updated my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell jquery that string is absolutely an 'ID', not a class.

**HTML ID attribute can't includes space, and must have at least one character. But for compatibility, better to avoid '_', '.'**

Here using the Javascript builtin method, and turn the DOM node to a Jquery object. It looks redundant, but it is steady and easy to read.

```js
$(function() {


  var xyz = 'XS_19MAY2016_012720_311.04$';
  e = $(document.getElementById(xyz + '_cal'));

  console.log(e.text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="XS_19MAY2016_012720_311.04$_cal">
  hello
</div>
```